# How to pass dictionary to functions?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to pass dictionary to user defined functions and I need to do some calculation based on the dictionary values. It is not working for me with functions but works fine without using functions. I am not sure, what is wrong with code. Any help please? No error message.

Input:

> "13-07-2016 12:55:46",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com" 
>   "13-07-2016 12:57:50",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com" 
>   "13-07-2016 13:00:43",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com" 
>   "13-07-2016 13:01:45",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com" 
>   "13-07-2016 13:02:57",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com" 
>   "13-07-2016 13:04:59",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com" 
>   "13-07-2016 13:06:51",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com" 
>   "13-07-2016 13:07:56",user,192.168.10.100,192.168.10.20,CONNECT,200,"www.abc.com"

Code:

```
file_name = sys.argv[1]
fo = open(file_name, "rb")


def setdict():
   dico,i={},0

   line = fo.readline()
   for line in fo:
     date, user, proxy_ip, client_ip, access_method, con, sites = line.split(",")
     sites = sites.rstrip('\n')
     dico[i]= date, user, proxy_ip, client_ip, access_method, con, sites
   return dico

def display(dico):
   for k,v in dico.items():
      print k,v
```

Comment: Your input data is not a dictionary

Comment: @chenchuk. It gets converted to one, so no worries there.

Comment: Your code as-written only opens the file (which I'm sure works just fine). Neither `setdict` nor `display` are ever called.

Comment: You never call the function `setdict`, so the dictionary never gets made.

Comment: You're not calling your functions. The `dico` in `def display(dico)` is not at all related to `return dico` from `def setdict()`. Your functions are doing nothing, hence why no error but also no activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A:** You should consider to call your functions at the end of the script:

```
dico = setdict()
display(dico)
```

Without that, they are declared, but not used.

**B:** You should also consider a better way to open your file:

```
with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  for line in lines:
    # Do stuff with your line
```

This is the best way to open a file in python and to read it line by line.

**C:** You are using:

```
   line = fo.readline()
   # ^ That line is never use after, you will loose all it's datas
   for line in fo:
     #do stuff on line
```

I've add a comment to show you that you loose the data from the first line.

**D:** You are using global variable (you use `fo` inside `setdict()` a better way will be to pass it by arguments:

```
fo = open(file_name, "rb")

def setdict(fo):
   dico,i={},0
   line = fo.readline()
   ...

setdict(fo)
```

Finally, here is how you can rewrite your script :

```
def setdict(filename):
   dico,i={},0
   with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   for line in f.readlines():
     date, user, proxy_ip, client_ip, access_method, con, sites = line.split(",")
     sites = sites.rstrip('\n')
     dico[i]= date, user, proxy_ip, client_ip, access_method, con, sites
   return dico

def display(dico):
   for k,v in dico.items():
      print k,v

file_name = sys.argv[1]
dico = setdict(filename)
display(dico)
```

Comment: I don't know. why is it is? Also I am getting single key,value pair. I thought it iterate through all lines and get displayed. Any suggestion?

Comment: @rmstmg I have edited my answer to add some explanation, please feel free to ask question if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a nice explanation !

Answer (score 1):

When you write a function in Python using the `def` keyword, the function is not automatically executed. You are never calling your `setdict` or `display` functions, just defining them so they can be called later.

Add this line to the end of your script to actually call the functions you defined:

```
display(setdict())
```

or more verbosely

```
dico = setdict()
display(dico)
```

Comment: For curiosity, you say "or more verbosely" but is `display(setdict())` more "pythonic"? I'm not sure I would use the first approach even if it saved me a line in this case.

Comment: @roganjosh Neither is especially more Pythonic. I merely meant that the second option takes an extra line of code. If the output of `setdict` is not going to be used again, the first option is fine. If it is going to be used, the second option is better.

Comment: @roganjosh. I think the key issue here is the dissonance between defining and calling a function in Python that comes from hearing that a script is executed line-by-line. I certainly remember having that in the beginning.

Comment: "Pythonistic"? I don't know where I got that word from, corrected :P Now I need to see what happens when the functions return and take more than one argument, also out of curiosity, because your first approach wouldn't even have occurred to me in my own code, even if I'm using similar constructs in libraries without ever being properly conscious of it. I would assume it fails because the `return` isn't unpacked.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Thank you so much. It's working now. :)

Comment: @rmstmg Glad it helped. Hope it helps you think about your scripts in a more general way in the future.

Comment: @rmstmg Oh, and don't forget to follow the pointers that Xavier C.'s answer provides.